# How do i place a list of values onto a drop down ?? (must use DOMs, no jquery)

Tags: javascript, list, dom, select

i'm trying to place a list of items onto a dropdown box but having little success. I have my list of items labelled MARKET, and i have a drop box using the "select" element, i've been trying all sorts of elements like .value and .option and .setAttribute but i dont know how to formulate the code using them, if there are any other elements i should be looking at then i would certainly like to know for future reference, but for the moment i would like to know how i can change my code so i can put a list of items onto a dropdown box !! Appreciate the help if there is any !!

```
var lbldiv = document.createElement("div");
var mklbl = document.createElement("label");
mklbl.innerHTML = "Market ";

var mkslct = document.createElement("select"); //dropdown

lbldiv.appendChild(mklbl);
lbldiv.appendChild(mkslct);

document.body.appendChild(lbldiv);

var markets = ["UK", "USA", "China"]; //list of markets


var mkul = document.createElement("ul"); //formulated list
mkul.className = "mkul";
for(var i = 0; i < markets.length; ++i){
    var crtli = document.createElement("li");
    crtli.value = i;
    crtli.innerHTML = markets[i];
mkul.appendChild(crtli);
}
document.body.appendChild(mkul);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function populateDDLB() {

var selectEl = document.getElementById("dropdownlistbox");
var options = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    selectEl.appendChild(el);

}

}

window.onload = populateDDLB;
```